# Binding both SelectedItem and SelectedValue in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

in a WPF application there's a list of telephone numbers.

```
class TelephoneNumber{
  public string Number {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
  
  private Employee _employee;
  public Employee Employee
  {
    get => _employee;
    set
    {
      _employee = value;
      EmployeeId = value?.Id ?? 0;
      if (EmployeeId == 0) return;
      LastName = value.LastName;
      FirstName = value.FirstName;
    }
  }
}

class Employee{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

A telephone number can have an arbitrary FirstName and LastName or can be linked to an Employee via its Id. In a WPF control the telephone numbers can be edited and all available Employees are displayed in a ComboBox. When the user selects an entry from the EmployeeComboBox I want the `LastName` and `FirstName` to be set to the selected Employee.

This is what I have so far, but the binding of the SelectedListItem (a `TelephoneNumber` object) doesn't seem to update the bound property if the Mode is set to `OneWayToSource`.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedListItem.EmployeeId, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem.Employee, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
/>
```

If the Mode of the `SelectedItem` binding is set to `TwoWay`, it does update the source property, but then it also uses that property to update the target property, which should be only done via the Id and the SelectedValue.

Why does this not work and is there a better way to set properties of the source depending on the SelectedItem of the ComboBox if I don't want to use that same property for determining which item should be selected in the ComboBox?

Comment: You don't bind both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`. It's one or the other. You'd better set the item to be selected programmatically (for example by handling `SelectionChanged`) if you don't want to two-bind.

Comment: Using both `SelectedItem` (for the target to source direction) and `SelectedValue` (for the source to target direction) would be convenient. I thought this would be a good solution since it works when the `SelectedItem` binding mode is set to `TwoWays`, but unfortunately there's no source update when set to `OneWayToSource`.